# What is the first and last value from INT32 that can be represented exactly in float?

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I know that precision is lost for floats above 2^24. My question is what is last int32 value which can be exactly represented in float and in the same time smaller than INT32_MAX. On the same principle what is the smallest int32 value with exact representation in float? I am talking about single precision floating point format. 
Thank you,

Comment: I am referring to(signed) int32 [-2147483648, 2147483647])  not uint32[0... 2^32 -1]. So I ma expecting a value around -2147483648 but with some difference ULPS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `float` here means IEEE 754 single-precision, as it almost always does, `INT32_MAX` rounds up to 2<sup>31</sup> when converted to `float`, so you can obtain the largest value representable exactly as `float` and as `int32_t` with:

```
nextafterf(INT32_MAX, 0)
```

That is: 2147483520

This number is 128 below 2<sup>31</sup>, consistent with the expectation that the ULP in the area would be 128, since we are 2<sup>7</sup> times above the maximum integer below which all integers are representable.

The smallest `int32_t` value also representable as a float is -2<sup>31</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to interpret this question is what are the largest/smallest int32_t values where adding/subtracting 1 results in a number that is exactly 1 more/less than the original number?

Since there are 23 + 1 = 24 bits in the mantissa the largest number that will fit there is 2^0+2^1 + ... +2^22+2^23 or 2^24-1 or 16777215. If you add one to this you will get simply 2^24 or 16777216. If you add one to 16777216 you will still have 16777216 because in the float format the maximum integer that may be incremented by one is 2^24-1.

After that, 2^24 to 2^25-2 may be increased by adding 2. From 2^25 to 2^26-4 increased by 4. 2^26 to 2^27-8 by 8 and so on.

Negative int32_t values function similarly: subtract 1 from 2^24-1 and you get -2^24. from -2^24 to -2^25-2 and so on.